# Obtaining list of file creation dates and concatenating pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am trying to get a list of file names and file creation dates from a directory and insert them in a pandas data frame but I am getting a type error.

TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Any help on how to do this would be create thanks

```
import os
import time
import pandas as pd

cur = os.getcwd()
folder = os.listdir(cur)

files = []
for f in folder:
    files.append(f)

creation = []
for cd in files:
    c = time.ctime(os.path.getctime(cd))
    creation.append(c)

filenames = pd.DataFrame(files, columns=['Files'])
file_creation = pd.DataFrame(creation, columns=['Date Created'])

df = pd.concat(filenames, file_creation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message says,that the first argument of `pd.concat` should be the sequence of series or dataframes to be concatenated. You passed one dataframe as first Argument and the other one as the second. But the second argument is already sth else, the axis to concatenate along in this case.

So try

```
df = pd.concat([filenames, file_creation], 1)
```

However, imo it is not the shortest way to first create two dataframes in order to concatenate them afterwards. You should create a final dataframe directly from the two lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Files': files, 'Date Created': creation})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're betting off building a generator of 2-tuples (filename and the timestamp converted to an actual datetime object), then build your DataFrame directly from that, eg:

```
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

files = (
    (file.name, pd.to_datetime(file.stat().st_ctime, unit='s'))
    for file in pathlib.Path.cwd().iterdir()
)

df = pd.DataFrame(files, columns=['Files', 'Creation Time'])
```